# How to create ListField containing image and multilnes text in a row -- blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I want to create ListField .In each row of Field i want to display image on the Right and text on the left.I am using the ListField and callback.The text and image is getting displayed but the text is overwriting on the image and also if i change the order i.e image on left and text on the right then the text is getting truncated and only a single line is coming where as the text is of multiple lines .So anyone could you please give an idea of how to proceed or way to do

thank you

Comment: visit this link here. [custom-listfield-in-blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/custom-listfield-in-blackberry.html)

Answer (score 2):

Which OS version are you using? If you are using OS6 or higher, consider using a `TableView`(and associated `TableModel` and `TableController`) . Its `DataTemplate` feature allows you more control over the layout of each row.

If you still want to use a `ListField` then you should show the code you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply .I will try to use thisway.

Comment: In table view can we set the listener for row.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check out the BlackBerry Advanced UI components here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

In particular check the ListStyleButtonField example.

Zip file containing Example BlackBerry Project:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/399/4/Advanced%20UI.zip

Once downloaded, do the following:

- Extract the Advanced UI folder to your local machine
- Open Eclipse and goto File->Import->Existing Project into workspace
- Choose the Advanced UI folder as the root folder

The Advanced UI project will then be imported into Eclipse and you should be able to build and run the sample application on the BlackBerry simulator. Once you see how ListStyleButtonField works you can copy it into your project, or modify it to your specific requirements.

Note that you may have to set your compiler compliance level to 1.3 to get this working. Do this under Project Settings->Java Compiler

Comment: but i am sorry to tell you i could find the class ListStyleButtonField.In my eclipse it asking to import that class. thank you

Comment: The Advanced UI components are not part of the core BlackBerry SDK. You will need to download and modify them to your needs. The link to download is at the bottom of the link above, but here it is for convenience: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/399/4/Advanced%20UI.zip

Comment: Updated the answer to include my comment above